# Differentiating with respect to vectors of unspecified length

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic, vector

Given a function defined by

```
f[x_,y_] := Sum[ x[[i]] (g[y[[i]]] - g[Total[y]] - Log[x[[i]]]), {i, 1, Length[x]}]
```

I can easily calculate the derivative for a fixed `n` by

```
D[f[{x1, x2, x3}, {y1, y2, y3}], {{x1, x2, x3}}]
```

which yields

```
{-g(y1 + y2 + y3) + g(y1) - log(x1) - 1,
 -g(y1 + y2 + y3) + g(y2) - log(x2) - 1,
 -g(y1 + y2 + y3) + g(y3) - log(x3) - 1}
```

I want to differentiate w.r.t. `x` in the general case, by something like this:

```
D[f[x, y], x]
```

yielding something like this:

```
{-g(Total[y]) + g(y[[i]]) - Log[x[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[x]}}
```

Is this possible?

Ideally it chains with `Solve` as well so that I can write something like:

```
Solve[D[f[x, y], x] == Table[0, {Length[x]}], x]
```

and get something like

```
{{x[[i]] -> E^(-g(Total[y]) + g(y[[i]]) - 1), {i, 1, Length[x]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using your definition of f[]:

```
f[x_,y_] := Sum[ x[[i]] (g[y[[i]]] - g[Total[y]] - Log[x[[i]]]), {i, 1, Length[x]}]
```

you can specify x and y as (say) 5-vectors using the construct `Array[x,5]` and `Array[y,5]` where you can replace `5` by any number. Then your function is explicitly:

```
f[ Array[x,5], Array[y,5] ]
```

and you can take the desired derivative with respect to the vector `Array[x,5]` using:

```
D[f[Array[x, 5], Array[y, 5]], {Array[x, 5]}]
```

You can then gather the terms together as you wish. So, it's not quite a general `n` but it works easily and simply for any fixed `n`.